# Avoid item label overlap in time series 1D plots (JFreeChart)

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am trying to find the best strategy to produce a 1D time based plot with labels. It currently looks like this:

[image]

The problem is there is spans of time where very little happens, and others with high density.

**What I would like to achieve is to distort the time axis** so that in the dense areas the labels are spaced apart to avoid overlap. Alternatively, I could imagine to show the actual data points without axis distortion, but distribute the labels so that they do not overlap.

---

**EDIT**: This is my attempt to clean up the mess manually, to get an idea of which output I would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might experiment with some combination of pan and zoom using `setDomainPannable()` and `setMouseWheelEnabled()`, seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065474/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/230513). Right-click to see the context menu and control-click to pan (option-click on Mac OS X).

Comment: Thanks, that is useful, although it doesn't solve the problem of getting out a nice looking PDF. I still need to manually distort the items, although being able to zoom+pan helps in the clean up process. I was more thinking of a non-linear transformation applied to the domain axis.

Comment: Maybe like Mac OS X Dock or Windows Magnifier? Sorry, I don't know of any support for automating this in `JFreeChart`.