# How to make zoom on mouse wheel [Java Swing]

Tags: java, swing, zooming, mousewheel

I edited [this program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java) and made building several plots. I want to make zoom on mouse wheel but I dont know how to do it. I know that I need to write my own `MouseWheelActionListener`. But how to make new boundaries of x and y axis and repaint my plots?

Comment: Here's a recent [tag:jfreechart] [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) using `setMouseWheelEnabled()`.

Comment: You could simply apply a `scale` to the `Graphics` context, but you'll also need to update the "expected" size of the component to match.  Something like [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643637/zoom-using-mouse-and-graphics/19646246#19646246)