# How to make mouse wheel zoom(setMouseWheelEnabled()) in Jfreechart only affect specific axis?

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

When I enable the mouse wheel zoom in my chart using this code line:

```
chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
```

Scrolling the mouse wheel will zoom in/out **both** x and y axis. How can I disable mouse wheel zooming on **one** of the axis?

Jfreechart Version: 1.0.13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) methods [`setDomainZoomable()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setDomainZoomable-boolean-) and [`setRangeZoomable()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#setRangeZoomable-boolean-) to control the axes individually. As a concrete example, edit `createChartPanel()` in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28519356/230513) as follows to enable zoom on the `"Value"` axis, while leaving the `"Count"` axis unchanged:

```
panel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
panel.setDomainZoomable(true);
panel.setRangeZoomable(false);
```

For convenience,

- Use the [context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19284972/230513) to change the zoom settings as needed.
- Use zoom buttons such as [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41544007/230513) as needed.
- Use other applicable features described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44151032/230513).

Zoomed in:
[image: zoomed in]

Zoomed out:
[image: zoomed out]

Comment: setDomainZoomable() and setRangeZooomable() only affect left-mouse's drag zoom. Mouse wheel zoom still zoom both axis. Will update again later.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the effect you describe with the complete example cited above. If you still have problems, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: I just run your histogram with my java 11 on Kubuntu 20.04. The wheel still zoom both axis. I guess this problem is platfrom dependent.  I can send a comment with screenshots as proof if you wish.

Comment: Ouch. No need for another [mcve]. Verify your JFreeChart version; I'm using JFreeChart version 1.5.0 on Java 1.8 on MacOS.

Comment: The problem solved after I upgrade jfreechart to 1.5.0, thank you, accepting your answer.